# Why does the .lower() in my if var in array: statement not work?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

```
if movie.lower() in movieList:
     if (youSure.lower()=="yes"):
       print("Removing '"+movie+"'")
       movieList.remove(movie)
```

My problem is that when running this, the program completely skips over the initial if statement

```
       if movie.lower() in movieList:
```

I have tried using .lower() on both *movie* and *movieList* individually as well as both at the same time, however, this hasn't had any effect.

Comment: Can you post the full snippet. It'll help me debug the issue better

Comment: What is `movieList`? Are all its contents lowercase? Please take the [tour], read [ask], and provide a [mre] that people can run that will reproduce your issue. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is .lower() function does not do operation inplace, maybe because strings are immutable in python(not sure if its the right reason).

```
movie_lowercase = movie.lower()
if movie_lowercase in movieList:
     if (youSure.lower()=="yes"):
       print("Removing '"+movie+"'")
       movieList.remove(movie)
```